# GLES 2.0 shader based filter for smooth skin

Tags: android, gpuimage

I'm currently using the [gpu-image port for android](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) to create a photo-editing app and want to apply a smooth skin filter.

After some google I found out the bilateral blur and median filter is some filter to achieve this effect.

But when trying to apply the bilateral blur in gpu-image the result isn't very satisfying 'cause it smooth down other part like eyebrow and lips.

Can anyone suggest me another good filter or maybe a way to combine several filter to achieve the smooth skin effect? I really want to replicate this: [like in the right-most image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEQYp.jpg)

Comment: no one is helping me.....? :(

Comment: You got any Success?

Comment: @AmniX No so much. I've found [this github project](https://github.com/wuhaoyu1990/MagicCamera) which has a beautify fs but it's not quite what I expected. You have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I Managed to Create the HighPassScalFilter for Android and It's On Github too.

> https://github.com/AmniX/HighPassSkinSmoothing-Android

**Implementation Is Like:**

[image]

**Theory**

The main theory behind High Pass Skin Smoothing is Frequency Separation.

Frequency separation splits up the tones and colors of a image from its more detailed textures. It is possible because a digital image can be interpreted as different frequencies represented as sine waves.

High frequencies in an image will contain information about fine details, such as skin pores, hair, fine lines, skin imperfections.

Low frequencies are the image data that contains information about volume, tone and color transitions. In other words: shadows and light areas, colors and tones.

https://fstoppers.com/post-production/ultimate-guide-frequency-separation-technique-8699
By using High Pass filter, the image can be separated into high and low spatial frequencies. Then we will be able to smoothing the image while preseving a fine level of detail by applying adjustments (Curve Adjustment in the diagram) to certain frequencies of the image.
Cheers.

Comment: I'm appreciate your effort on creating this and turn out it works really well. However I'm finding a real-time solution with GLSL by the GPUImage framework 'cause the image is rendered by GLES instead of Bitmap. Will try to find a way with your theory, +1 by the way

Comment: Let me know about the same whenever its done,

Btw, there is a Library for iOS which uses GPUImage for the same.

Here is the Link.
https://github.com/YuAo/YUGPUImageHighPassSkinSmoothing

Comment: The provided link is broken, this is for the later comes https://github.com/msoftware/HighPassSkinSmoothing-Android. I'm not sure if it is the one AmniX provided or not, so I comment here instead of editing the AmniX's answer

Comment: @AmniX is it possible High Pass Skin Smoothing in real time camera?

Comment: @AmniX my question is same as #Akash is it possible High Pass skin smoothing in real time camera?

Comment: Now it's not working in android 11